# Using Http Post to AddList() in Sharepoint

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, list, http-post

On a remote client, I'm trying to create a new list in a sharepoint site. Right now, I'm building a CAML string and sending it via http post to my sharepoint site. I've used this method to update list items and create dws folders, but I can't seem to get AddList to work. I get an error "Remove server returned error:NotFound."

here is my CAML:

```
        string soapEnv =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        "<soap:Envelope " + "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" +
        "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"" +
        " xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
        "<soap:Body>" +
        "<AddList xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap\">" +
            "<listName>" + listName + "</listName>" +
            "<description>" + "A Test list" + "</description>" +
            "<templateID>100</templateID>" +
        "</AddList>" +
        "</soap:Body>" +
        "</soap:Envelope>";
        return soapEnv;
```

I send this in an http Post with these settings:

```
        uri = "[my sharepoint site]/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["SOAPAction"] = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
        client.Headers["content-type"] = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        client.UploadStringCompleted += UploadStringCompleted;
        try
        {
            client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute), "POST", CAML);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in upload string async: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Any ideas? I'm pretty certain it's not an authentication issue since I've used the exact same method in this same program to do the previously mentioned functions. The sharepoint site I'm adding the list to is a test site in which I have full read/write capabilities.

Comment: also, forgot to mention it's in a silverlight app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! 
In this part of the **soap:Envelope** tag: "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
I had XMLSchema-instance" instead of XMLSchema**\"**".  
  I needed that extra parentheses to finish that string...